# "App" function returns a wrong output format

Tags: r, terra

I'm practicing with `terra` package and land cover classification using [the example](https://rspatial.org/rs-terra/5-supclassification.html) provided with the package materials.
Unfortunately, right in the end, the `app()` function throws this error

```
> lulc <- app(classified, fun = which.max)
Error: [app] the function returns a list (should be numeric or matrix
```

and I can't assign the colour ramp to classes. I checked the `classified` input and looks ok but my only idea is that the error might be related to some kind of `NA` or missing value.

I found no other similar error on the web.
Any help on what to look for for a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is indeed likely because you raster has `NA` values, and `which.max(NA)` does not return `NA`.

```
which.max(NA)
#integer(0)
```

So this leads to an error

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(ncols=10, nrows=10)
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)
r[,1] = NA
x <- c(r, sqrt(r)+50, r-50)
s <- app(x, fun=which.max)
# Error: [app] 'fun' returns a list (should be numeric or matrix). Perhaps because returned values have different lenghts?
```

You can wrap `which.max` inside another function that fixes this behavior, for example like this:

```
f <- function(i) c(which.max(i), NA)[1] 
f(1:5)
#[1] 5
f(NA)
#[1] NA
```

And use it with `app`

```
s <- app(x, fun=f)
```

However, in this case, the easiest approach is to use `which.max` directly (and I will change the tutorial to show that)

```
which.max(x)
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 10, 10, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 36, 18  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#source      : memory 
#name        : which.max 
#min value   :         1 
#max value   :         2
```

Comment: great. I don't know if it might be an idea but, in case, a solution could be to allow additional parameters for the input functions, such as `fun = which.max(na.rm=T)`

Comment: You can pass additional parameters to fun, via the ellipses (`...`). But `which.max` does not take any.